# WPF Menu Item doesn't get closed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to re-style my ContextMenu with following style

```
   <ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuItemTemplateKey}" TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="22" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
        <Grid>
           <Button>
                <ContentPresenter 
                        Name="HeaderHost"
                        ContentSource="Header"
                        RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Border}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Once I click on my context menu item it triggers my call back but the menu itself stays on the screen. How can I trigger closing logic?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Button` is handling the click event and stopping it from bubbling up the visual tree to the `MenuItem`.

Setting `IsHitTestVisible` on the Button would stop the `Button` handling the click event, but would also stop `MouseOver/Pressed` styling.

```
<Button IsHitTestVisible="False">
    <ContentPresenter 
    Name="HeaderHost"
    ContentSource="Header"
    RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
</Button>
```